# HTML5 File vs. java.io.File

Tags: javascript, applet, fileapi

How do I pass a file uploaded in Javascript using [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) to an applet method that takes a Java [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) argument? I have read [LiveConnect](https://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#JS_JAVA_OBJECTS) but did not find specific information about working with files.

Comment: The short answer is: You don't.  Files stored locally via the FileSystem API are only supposed to be accessed via the API (which, of course, restricts you to JavaScript). Any other access -- such as attempts to access the file directly through the user's operating system by file reference -- is not the correct approach.  The API provides a "virtual" file system, not a real one that you can access directly.

Comment: In addition to the advice of @PhilNicholas, note that the applet runs locally on the client, while the HTML 5 file support is for uploading the file to the *server.*  For an applet to access such a resource would require the server to send the content of the file back to the applet, meaning the user would suffer a 'bandwidth hit' for the file (twice) while the server would have to deal with a file that isn't really needed on the server.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Ah, good catch. This question is mis-tagged as "HTML5-FileSystem" which is a completely different API from the FileAPI (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileapi).  I'll submit it to have the tag corrected.